# Selecting Usernames Uniquely

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

Suppose that I have a table with a column labeled `Name`, which contains (possibly) repeating entries of unique usernames. What LINQ-to-SQL statement can I write to uniquely traverse the usernames? In other words:

Here is an example of the table:

```
Name    Log
User1   05/13/13
User2   05/13/13
User2   05/14/13
User3   05/15/13
User1   05/15/13
```

I want to select usernames uniquely:

```
User1, User2, User3.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean linq-to-sql? Or are you asking for linq on an IEnumerable? Or are you asking for the sql query?

Comment: Do you mean you want to group the logs by user, or you just want a list of distinct usernames?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM TABLE;
```

or in LinQ;

```
var names = Table.Select( t => t.Name ).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a linq query and use the .Distinct extension method on the result.
Example:

```
var users = (from logfile in logfiles select logfile.Name).Distinct();
```

Comment: Would `from logfile in logfiles select logfile.Name order by logfile.Name` also work? I'm new to linq but it looks like `Distinct` would have to run through the list a second time to remove duplicates where order by *may* not. But I'm not sure order by will for sure get the job done.